# Duplicate a line of text and add right prefix in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to duplicate each line but I have to mod second one also.
Ex:

My input data is:

> C:\Dir\Dir2\Dir3

Final should look like this:

> Source:C:\Dir\Dir2\Dir3 Destination:http://mymachine/se/docs/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3

I was managed to make:

> Source:C:\Dir\Dir2\Dir3 Destination:C:\Dir\Dir2\Dir3

by

> find "^.*$" replace with "Source:$0 Destination:$0"

I have to replace "C:\" with "http://mymachine/se/docs/" and "\" with "/".

How to do this?

Comment: This is a little confusing, can you clarify exactly what you want as your output?

Comment: Try searching for `^.*\\(.)$` and replacing it with `Source:$0 Destination:$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/dxo94q/2)

```
[^\\]+\\(.*)
```

Replacement: `Source:$0 Destination:http://mymachine/se/docs/$1`

To fix the backslash issue, you'll need to run a second regex replace after the one above. See below:

```
\bDestination:[^\\\v]*\K\\
```

Replacement: `/`

---

### Results

#### Input

```
C:\Dir1
```

#### Output

```
Source:C:\Dir1 Destination:http://mymachine/se/docs/Dir1
```

---

### Explanation

**First pattern**

- `[^\\]+` Match any character except backslash `\` one or more times
- `\\` Match a literal backslash character `\`
- `(.*)` Capture any character any number of times (greedy) into capture group 1 (everything after the first backslash in the string)

**Second pattern**

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `Destination:` Match this literally
- `[^\\\v]*` Match any number of any character except backslash `\` and vertical whitespace characters
- `\K` Reset the pattern's match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\\` Match a literal backslash

Comment: I used this solution on final data and we have some issues. I have updated main post. Can you see it?

Comment: @MichalG see my edits above. I've added a second regex to fix the backslash issue. You need to run the first then the second regex.